# как сделать less.less в less.min.css в phpStorm?

Tags: css, phpstorm, less, min, watch

В phpStorme есть watcher который компилит стили less в css. А как минифицировать css, который собран из less?  -  т.е. нужно получить на выходе **.min.css .

Answer (score 0):

https://less-lang.info/usage/   -   оказалось надо было установить less-plugin-clean-css и в watcher когда выбираем less в начале строки argements прописываем --clean-css (будет вся строка: --clean-css --no-color $FileName$) ( http://prntscr.com/jauc47 )